# How to check the (absolute) memory usage of a process?

Tags: memory, memory-management, ps

I have a server process running with pid `24257` and would like to know how much memory it is using (in order to estimate how much resources to allocate for the same process in Kubernetes). According to the man page for `ps` (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html), this can be obtained with the `%mem` output format specifier:

```
       %mem        %MEM      ratio of the process's resident set size
                             to the physical memory on the machine,
                             expressed as a percentage.  (alias pmem).
```

If I run this, I get

```
> ps -p 24257 -o %mem
%MEM
 0.3
```

I'm not sure I understand this output, because I'm running the process on a MacBook Pro with 64 GB of memory, so I would expect the (Terminal) process to show up in the Activity Monitor as using ~19 GB of memory. However, the Terminal processes running are nowhere near that (they are at most ~900 Mb).

Is there a way I can get the memory usage as an absolute number (in Mb)? Or otherwise, how do I determine the "physical memory on the machine" used for this calculation?

Comment: 0.3% of 64GB is 192 MB, not 19 GB.

Comment: Anyway, if resident set size is what you mean by "memory usage" (there are other possible notions), there's an RSS field in `ps`, as well as in `/proc/PID/status`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To convert [Nate Eldredge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/634919/nate-eldredge)'s comments to an answer, firstly, the `0.3` output is a percentage, so 0.3% of 64 GB is 192 MB.

Secondly, the `rss` output should give the resident set size:

```
       rss         RSS       resident set size, the non-swapped physical
                             memory that a task has used (in kilobytes).
                             (alias rssize, rsz).
```

Running this command gives

```
> ps -p 24257 -o %mem,rss
%MEM    RSS
 0.3 209908
```

The output of ~21 Mb agrees pretty well with the estimate of ~19 Gb derived from the `%MEM` output.